# Apache HTTP server starts blocking requests after some time

Tags: apache

My hosting uses Apache server and I am connecting to the same url from the same client application which makes 10-20 requests per minute and after some time the server starts blocking the client app which shows errors for unreachable address and connection refused etc. 
I am sure this isn't a connectivity issue as it is consistently reproducible.

Any ideas how to setup the server so it won't block the client app's ip address?

Comment: maybe you max out the number of apache threads possible under your settings

Comment: I'd say before reconfiguring a server you should find out what is actually going on. Start by reading log files!

Comment: @arkascha you are right. I also want to get to the bottom of this. Which log files should I read - what are their names? I am new to apache configuration. My server uses cPanel for web administration.

Comment: I have no idea about cPanel. But the apache configuration contains the log files location. Typical that is /var/log/apache2/ or /var/log/httpd/, but it may vary, depending on the setup and also the complexiy. Look through the servers configuration, watch out for options with a 'log' inside their name ;-) Also, as a second step, sniffing the web requests on network level might be a starting point. You could use `wireshark` or `tcpdump` for that.